# Rename Root @ local host username mySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to rename the root username to something else, I am using the following code, however, I get an error :(

```
RENAME USER 'root'@'localhost' TO 'chosenName'@'localhost';
```

I get the following error ...

```
ERROR 1396 (HY000) : Operation RENAME USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'
```

Comment: Be sure that user `'username'@'localhost'` exists. To show all the users run this query: `SELECT Host,User FROM mysql.user;`.
NOTE: `'username'@'localhost'` and `'username'@'%'` are two different users.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this as following

```
UPDATE mysql.user set user = <newrootname> where user = 'root';
FLUSH privileges;
```

Answer (score 4):

try this it will definitely work but only just make sure no mistake in syntax

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set user="new_user" where user="root";
mysql> flush privileges;
```

Comment: I used `'` instead of `"`.